# SQL Select - Get a count of data as a separate column error

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, where-clause

I am working on this query whereas I have a table as follows

```
Code | Date   
-------------
001  | 20-JUN     
001  | 20-JUN    
002  | 20-JUN 
003  | 20-JUN    
002  | 20-JUN   
001  | 20-JUN   
002  | 21-JUN
```

I need to get a count of codes in a separate column only for the date of 20-JUN

```
Code | Count
--------------
001  |  3
002  |  2
003  |  1
```

Here's the query I am trying.

```
SELECT
    ll.code,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            lab_tests ltb
        WHERE
            ltb.code = ll.code
            AND ltb.date = ll.date
    ) AS Count
FROM
    lab_tests ll
WHERE
    ll.date = '20-JUN'
```

This however does not give me the desired outcome, except it returns this.

```
Code | Count
--------------
001  |  1
001  |  1
001  |  1
002  |  1
002  |  1
003  |  1
```

I still cannot figure out how to change the query to get the outcome I need. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, sql-server, postgresql...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to just want aggregation:

```
select t.code, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
where t.date = date '2020-06-20'
group by t.code
```

This assumes that `date` is stored as a date, and that your database, which you did not tell, supports the standard syntax to declare literal dates.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. In my query, I am actually filtering records as 'date like %30-JUN%' so the data type of date was not so important.